# Jersey 1.9 and advanced validation

Tags: jersey, bean-validation

I'm using Jersey 1.9 with validation support and having a resource method like:

```
@POST
public Response createNewOozieTransformation(
    @FormDataParam("info") SomeInfo info,
    @FormDataParam("zippedResources") InputStream zippedResources) {

    ...
    Collection<Resource> resources = resourcesService.extractResources(zippedResources);

    //This needs to be validated
    RequestWithResources requestWithResources = new RequestWithResources(info, resources);

    someService.handle(requestWithResources);
}
```

I'm using bean validation for `SomeInfo`, some of it's paramters are e.g. `@NotNull` and this all works fine. I want to validate the `RequestWithResouces` as well but I don't know how. Please note that `SomeInfo` contains dynamic information on what are the required resources so I need the whole `RequestWithResources` to be able to perform the validation.

My `RequestWithResources` has custom `@ValidateMandatoryResources` annotation on class level:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValidateMandatoryResources.ResourcesValidator.class)
public @interface ValidateMandatoryResources {

    ...

    class ResourcesValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidateMandatoryResources, RequestWithResources> {
        ...
    }
}
```

What I have tried without luck:

1. Created a method which creates the `RequestWithResources` annotating with `@ValidateOnExecution`. - validator was not invoked
2. As `someService` is injected into the controller I tried to annotate the `ReqeuestWithResources` parameter in it's  `handle(...)` with `@Valid` - validator was not executed
3. `@Inject` `Validator` into the controller class and run the `validate(requestWithResources)` on it. - dies because cannot inject `Validator`

Comment: Your 3rd option will work if you enable CDI. This depends of course of your run time env for CDI availability which you did not mention.

Comment: I don't have CDI enabled container unfortunately. I hoped the Validator which Jersey uses may be available through the HK2 though. Any insight where Jersey gets the Validator which it uses for resource method parameters validation?

Comment: It seems jersey is using hibernate impl for BV. You can create a default ValidatorFactory this way:ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator(); However I don't know how to get hold of the one created by jersey

Comment: Yep, did exactly that. Thought using the Jersey's one will be cleaner but this is probably acceptable. Wanna make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a default ValidatorFactory this way:

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(); 
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
```

However you'll have a second ValidatorFactory in memory as it seems not possible to get hold of the one instantiated by jersey.